# Change value of textview only using Kotlin without affecting default size

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am changing the value of a textview programmatically.

XML:

```
 <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:text="test"
                android:textSize="45px"/>
```

Kotlin:

```
   name.text = "John Doe"
```

However when I use the above Kotlin code, the textSize also changes to default.

How do I keep the `textSize="45px"` ?

Comment: set name.textSize="45px" after changing the name

Comment: @JawadMalik this piece of code doesn't work. It's not possible to set a textSize programmatically with a String.

Comment: yes if you use dp instead of px then it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options.

The first option is, that you replace `px` with `dp`.
Then your `TextView` looks like this:

```
<TextView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/name"
       android:text="test"
       android:textSize="45dp"/>
```

In the second option you just add `name.textSize= 45f` to your code.
Then your MainActivity looks like this:

```
name.text = "John Doe"
name.textSize= 45f
```